# UWP protocol activation if returned via HTTP 302 redirect

Tags: uwp

Today I faced very strange difference in how "Protocol Activation" (custom URI scheme handling) works on desktops and phones for the same UWP project deployed on, respectively. On desktops, you got your app activated successfully. On phones, it says you have to install appropriate app from the Store to deal with your custom URI scheme (and indeed you have your app installed on the phone before, and even have it running right now - why to search the Store?).

Important note: if you type that custom URI right into the browser window, you're ok on both hardwares. The issue appears if the custom URI is returned as a result of HTTP request, via correct HTTP 302 redirection. So, the full use-case is "request normal URL -> response HTTP 302 to custom URI location"

Finally, I came into conclusion that mobile version of Edge doing something different on 302-redirects if compared with desktop browsers. Quickly composing the simplest app with XAML WebView and UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified event handler, I learned that two things:

1. Desktop WebView sees your redirect URIs as "yourapp://host/?params-list", everything is ok
2. Phone WebView sees your redirect URI in escaped form like "**intent:**//yourapp/**confirm**?params-list#**Intent**;**scheme=yourapp**;**end**" (so host part is lost completely, other parts are escaped)

My questions are:

1. Why phone does that intent-escaping?
2. What are best-practices to have "Protocol Activation" working on both desktop and phone in the same codebase scope?

Comment: Does you phone has installed that APP? It seems if there is no app in your device, it will search the Store?

Comment: @Scavenger, for sure I have, see above: [quote](and indeed you have your app installed on the phone before, and even have it running right now - why to search the Store?).[/quote]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue was caused by server-side logic (with naïve substring search in User-Agent header provided by desktop browser or phone browser).

Backend guys! Never, NEVER trust user-agent string!

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 6.0.1; Microsoft; Lumia 950
>   Dual SIM) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116
>   Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063